# ENOENT every time I put a function inside an express.js server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to build a simple wrapper for the tesseract.js API so I can use it with a simple GET request within Google Apps Script and I'm having some trouble. For some reason it works perfectly but as soon as I put the same code inside of the express server I keep getting this:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
```

Here's the code:

```
const Tesseract = require('tesseract.js')
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')
require('custom-env').env();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

const url = 'http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png'

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if (req.query.imageUrl) {
      const filename = 'pic.png'
      const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'pic.png');
      const writeFile = fs.createWriteStream(tempFilePath);
      console.log('got here');
      request(url).pipe(writeFile).on('close', function() {
        console.log(url, 'saved to', tempFilePath)
        Tesseract.recognize(tempFilePath)
          .progress(function  (p) {})
          .catch(err => console.error(err))
          .then(function (result) {
            res.send(result.text);
            process.exit(0);
          })
      });
      fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
  } else {
      res.send('Send a URL you muppet!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tesseract.recognize` is async and returns a promise. Yet you are calling `fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);` immediately after `recognize()` which will execute before `recognize()` completes. This race can mean the file is killed before you are done processing.

You should remove the unlink into the `then` so that you only unlink when complete.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if (req.query.imageUrl) {
      const filename = 'pic.png'
      const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'pic.png');
      const writeFile = fs.createWriteStream(tempFilePath);
      console.log('got here');
      request(url).pipe(writeFile).on('close', function() {
        console.log(url, 'saved to', tempFilePath)
        Tesseract.recognize(tempFilePath)
          .progress(function  (p) {})
          .catch(err => console.error(err))
          .then(function (result) {
            res.send(result.text);
            fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
          })
      });
  } else {
      res.send('Send a URL you muppet!');
  }
});
```

Comment: sorry, i've added the dependencies at the top - i'm pretty sure request is defined as it is

Comment: Move your `fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);` statement ^^

Comment: Can't believe how much more simple this was then I thought, thanks!

Comment: No prob, normally more simple than we think